# Kramdown/coderay will not parse code snippets using html in Jekyl/Octopress

Tags: jekyll, octopress, coderay, kramdown

I have a website that is using Octopress (Which uses Jekyl). Here is my codeblock that I want to display the color highlighting syntax for:

```
~~~
def what?
    42
end
~~~
{:lang='ruby}
```

If this is in a file.markdown file it is parsed correctly and I see the proper code syntax. If it is in file.html it is not parsed into a code syntax. What can I do to parse this correctly in an html file?

Answer (score 1):

That
[does not work](http://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/pull/15)
anymore. Use

```
~~~
def what?
  42
end
~~~
{:.language-ruby}
```

or better yet

```
~~~ ruby
def what?
  42
end
~~~
```

[Example](http://raw.github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/source/_posts/2012-01-31-code-test.md)

> Markdown does not work when the file extension is html.

Markdown [can work with html](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure).

> Provided that the file has a YAML Front Matter section, it will be 
>   transformed by Jekyll. The same will happen for any .html, .markdown, .md, 
>   or .textile file in your site's root directory or directories not listed 
>   above.