# How to add class="CodeRay" in Octopress

Tags: jekyll, octopress, coderay, kramdown

I am using kramdown in Octopress for a while. I wanted to add CodeRay to my Octopress. I installed coderay.

```
➜  octopress git:(source) ✗ sudo gem install coderay
Password:
Successfully installed coderay-1.0.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for coderay-1.0.9...
Installing RDoc documentation for coderay-1.0.9...
```

I changed _config.yml

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  use_coderay: true
  coderay:
    coderay_line_numbers: table
    coderay_css: class
```

I have added sass/custom/_coderay-github.scss and I can see them in my CSS.

I used the followings but none of them added  tag to my html so that it does not render CodeRay css.

```
~~~
def hello
  puts "hello world"
end
~~~
{:lang="ruby"}
```

Indented:

```
    puts "hello world"
{:lang="ruby"}
```

How can I add CodeRay to my Octopress?

I am following this [post](http://blog.codebykat.com/2013/05/23/gorgeous-octopress-codeblocks-with-coderay/).

Comment: have you added  kramdown and coderay to your Gemfile ?

Comment: Yes, I have them. And I did bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705237/kramdown-coderay-will-not-parse-code-snippets-using-html-in-jekyl-octopress).

```
~~~
def what?
  42
end
~~~
{:.language-ruby}
```

Or

```
~~~ ruby
def what?
  42
end
~~~
```